# Matplotlib - when plotting time it puts decimal zeros after the seconds

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib, format

Here is the plot I have currently:

[image]

The 'time' strings I import are like this: 08:12:46, so I would like to cut the zeros at the end, but I can't seem to find the problem. Also, is there a way to show the floats on the Y axis in the exponential format, which is the one I am importing from the csv?

I just started to look into matplotlib and numpy for work, so if you have some advice it would be fantastic.

Thank you in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

print(plt.style.available)

style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('C:\\Users\\arzuffi pc test\\Desktop\\VMI WIP - Copia (2)\\Cycle info\\_Current Cycle.csv','r').read()
    #graph_data = open('C:\\Users\\arzuffi pc test\\Desktop\\Visual Machine Interface Alpha 1.4.3\\Cycle info\\_Current Cycle.csv','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    skip = 0
    for line in lines:        
        if skip < 7:
            skip += 1
        else:                
            if len(line) > 1:
                time, cycle, pc, pd, co, hv, cr, ph, gd_volt, gd_amp, gd_power, eva_amp, eva_volt, p_rpm, p_amp, r1_rpm, r1_amp, r2_rpm, r2_amp, hmdso, gas, ahc, diff_l, diff_r = line.split(';')
                #x, y = line.split(';')
                print(time)
                print(pc)
                xs.append(dt.datetime.strptime(time,'%H:%M:%S'))#.date())
                ys.append(pc)

        #print(i)
    #xs = matplotlib.dates.date2num(xs)    
    print(xs)    
    if len (xs) > 100:
        xs = xs[-100:]
    if len (ys) > 100:
        ys = ys[-100:] 
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```

these are the data:
[image]

Comment: Please try to add the code and images in the question itself.

Comment: it doesn't let me put images, converts them into links automatically. Added the code as text though.

Comment: Could you add some sample data from the file? This would make it easier to recreate the problem.

Comment: Since it doesn't let me add this in the initial post, here you can download the csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JDncFvHtJ3ZDJSakNlWDc3cWM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the format to be used as follows:

```
xs = matplotlib.dates.date2num(xs)    # You need to keep this line

hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
ax1.plot(xs, ys)   # You have this already
```

This would give you an output as follows:

[image: matplot with time formatting]

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much :)